# ruamel.yaml: insert a value given dynamic index and unknown depth

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

Using ruamel, I need to add new values to a yaml file where the index (and depth) is not known until runtime. Is there a way to insert a value if I'm given the entire path for the index? (I can decide the format for the index)

i.e. Given the following yaml:

```
app:
  datasource:
    url:example.org
    username:myuser
    password:mypw
```

I need to add a new value to this yaml file. If I'm given the index `app:datasource:port` and value `myport`, then I want the output to be:

```
app:
  datasource:
    url:example.org
    username:myuser
    password:mypw
    port:myport
```

**What I tried**

I tried just putting the entire index inside square brackets `[]`  or use `.insert()`, but neither of these work:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
with open('myfile.yaml', 'r') as stream:
  code = yaml.load(stream)

  # assume this index isn't known until runtime
  index = 'app:datasource:port'
  other_index = 'app:datasource:other_port'

  code[index] = 'myport'
  code.insert(1, other_index, 'otherport')

  yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

it produces the following output which isn't what I want. It just treats them as a top level index rather than a nested one:

```
app:
  datasource:
    url:example.org
    username:myuser
    password:mypw
app:datasource:port: myport
app:datasource:other_port: otherport
```

**What can I do to insert a value at a dynamically provided index?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your input file doesn't load to what you expect it loads to. The value for `datasource` is **not**
a mapping, but unquoted multi-line string. That is because there has to be
a space after the value indicator (`:`), unless both the key and value are quoted.
Since your `index` and `other_index` are just strings (that happen to have a colon in them),
these are used as keys for assigning to the root level mapping (your `code`).

When you load a YAML document, such as yours, that has a mapping at the root, you'll get
an instance of `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap` as a result. That instance has a method, `mlget`,
that takes a list of "index-segments", that are used to recursively traverse the
data structure. You can use that to easily find the parent of your "index" and set
the value.

Assuming you put a space after the colon of the last three lines of your input:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml


def _mlput(self, path, value, index=None, sep=':'):
    spath = path.split(sep)
    parent = self.mlget(spath[:-1])
    if index is None:
        parent[spath[-1]] = value
    else:
        parent.insert(index, spath[-1], value)

ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap.mlput = _mlput
    
path = Path('myfile.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(path)
data.mlput('app:datasource:port', 'myport')
data.mlput('app:datasource:other_port', 'otherport', 1)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
app:
  datasource:
    url: example.org
    other_port: otherport
    username: myuser
    password: mypw
    port: myport
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks for catching that I was also missing the spaces. Saved me from running into problems later down the road.